# Не работают прокси в requests

Tags: python, requests

Работаю с запросами и нужно подключить прокси. Что я делаю не так?

```
session.proxies = {'http':'socks5://185.227.111.235:1080}
```

далее делаю запрос на 2ip и беру от туда айпи. Но Ip  почему-то мой,а не прокси. Как это пофиксить?

```
html  = session.get('https://2ip.ru/').text
html = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(html.find(class_='ip').text) #выводит мой ip
```

Comment: Возможно, потому что в прокси указан http, а запрос делаете на https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте протокол `https` в `proxies`:

```
session.proxies = {
    'http':'socks5://185.227.111.235:1080',
    'https':'socks5://185.227.111.235:1080',
}
```

ps иногда `socks5` не работает в `requests`, пометяйте на `socks5h`

Comment: Хорошо. Это работает. Но теперь у меня есть прокси http. Через них не все равно не хочет работать

Comment: proxy = {'http':'http://104.28.6.142:80','https': 'https://104.28.6.142:80')

Comment: в адресе нужен протокол: {
  “http”: “http : // 10.10.10.10:8000”,
  “https”: “http : // 10.10.10.10:8000”,
} (без пробелов)