# Как работать с api через прокси?

Tags: python, proxy

Опишу очень просто
Вот есть код который получает данные напрямую

```
def getBalance(addr):
try:
    response = requests.get(
        f'https://api.smartbit.com.au/v1/blockchain/address/{addr}')
    return (
        Decimal(response.json()["address"]["total"]["balance"])
    )
except:
    pass
```

Как Как бы мне сделать что это все работало через список прокси?

Comment: Думаю , что решения вашей проблемы описано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module)

Comment: [один](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1228066/420098), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1245058/420098)